# Target only newly added elements pushed in array

Tags: javascript

I am currently using a js script (tinymasonry) and am successfully adding new items to the grid. the items have an opacity 0 class (op0) which is removed when they are loaded.

This works fine on initial load, and on resize for all the elements, but I am trying to get this fade effect to happen also on ONLY the new pushed elements. This is where I get stuck.

here is my code:

```
function TinyMasonry(el) {
  var self = this
  var columns = []

  function createColumns(n) {
    var width = 100 / n + "%"
    columns = []
    while (n--) {
      var column = document.createElement("div")
      column.style.width = width
      column.style.float = "left"
      el.appendChild(column)
      columns.push(column)
    }
  }

  function getShortest() {
    var shortest = columns[0]
    for (var i = columns.length; i--;) {
      if (columns[i].clientHeight <= shortest.clientHeight) {
        shortest = columns[i]
      }
    }
    return shortest
  }

  function layout(tested) {
    var width = tested.parentElement.clientWidth / tested.clientWidth
    var n = Math.min(42, Math.round(width)) || 1
    var child
    while (child = el.firstElementChild) {
      child.parentNode.removeChild(child)
    }
    el.style.overflow = "hidden"
    createColumns(n)
    self.items.forEach(function(item,index) {
      item.style.display = "block"
      item.style.width = "auto"
      item.style.visibility = ""
      getShortest().appendChild(item)
      setTimeout(function() {
        item.classList.remove('op0')
      }, (100 * (index + 1)));

    })
    el.style.minHeight = ""
  }

  self.update = function() {
    if (self.items[0]) {
      el.classList.add("tinyMasonryLoaded")
      if (columns[0]) {
        el.style.minHeight = el.clientHeight + "px"
      }
      var tested = self.items[0]
      tested.style.width = ""
      if (tested.parentNode && tested.parentNode.parentNode === el) {
        layout(tested)
      } else {
        el.appendChild(tested)
        setTimeout(layout.bind(0, tested))
      }
    }
  }

  self.items = [].slice.call(el.children)
  self.update()

  var resizer;
  var startWidth = window.innerWidth;

  function resizeTimeout() {
      clearTimeout(resizer);
      resizer = setTimeout(doneResizing, 100)
  } 

  function doneResizing() {
    var curWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var breakpoint = false;
      if ((startWidth >= 580 && curWidth < 580) || (startWidth <= 580 && curWidth > 580)) {
          breakpoint = true
      }
      else if ((startWidth >= 980 && curWidth < 980) || (startWidth <= 980 && curWidth > 980)) {
          breakpoint = true
      }
      if(breakpoint === true) {
          self.items.forEach(function(item,index) {
            item.classList.add('op0')
          })
          self.update()
      }
      startWidth = window.innerWidth;
  }

  window.addEventListener("resize", resizeTimeout)
}

if (typeof exports === "object") {
  module.exports = TinyMasonry
}

var masGridContainer = document.querySelector(".mas-grid");
var masGrid = new TinyMasonry(masGridContainer);
```

Then on ajax response I add the elements with:

```
for (index = elements.length - 1; index >= 0; --index) {
    masGrid.items.push(elements[index]);
}
masGrid.update();
```

If I add a loop at the start of the update function such as:

```
self.items.forEach(function(item,index) {
        item.classList.add('op0')
    })
```

The opacity effects shows up on all the items when the new ones are added.

How can I have the effect show ONLY on the new added items when the update() fun is called after ajax response?

Comment: Still looking for a proper implementation to my code. The answer by Arjun Rajagopalan is probably right but aftrer several  tries I havent been able to implement it a s asolution.

Comment: can you provide a working snippet with HTML structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your code and example, you're just pushing the elements you got via an ajax response into the grid. Since `push` always adds items to the end of the array, you can just *remember* the last index you added, for example:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 'sun', 'banana', 4, 'foo'];
var lastKnownIndex = 4;

// all elements added
var addedElements = arr.slice(lastKnownIndex + 1);

// process added elements
console.log(addedElements);

// update index
lastKnownIndex = arr.length - 1;
```

See [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Unfortunately, you did not provide the HTML/CSS for your code.
This, however, is how I would put it into your code according to your text:

```js
function TinyMasonry(el) {
  var self = this
  var columns = []
  var lastKnownIndex = 0

  function createColumns(n) {
    var width = 100 / n + "%"
    columns = []
    while (n--) {
      var column = document.createElement("div")
      column.style.width = width
      column.style.float = "left"
      el.appendChild(column)
      columns.push(column)
    }
  }

  function getShortest() {
    var shortest = columns[0]
    for (var i = columns.length; i--;) {
      if (columns[i].clientHeight <= shortest.clientHeight) {
        shortest = columns[i]
      }
    }
    return shortest
  }

  function layout(tested) {
    var width = tested.parentElement.clientWidth / tested.clientWidth
    var n = Math.min(42, Math.round(width)) || 1
    var child
    while (child = el.firstElementChild) {
      child.parentNode.removeChild(child)
    }
    el.style.overflow = "hidden"
    createColumns(n)
    self.items.forEach(function(item,index) {
      item.style.display = "block"
      item.style.width = "auto"
      item.style.visibility = ""
      getShortest().appendChild(item)
      setTimeout(function() {
        item.classList.remove('op0')
      }, (100 * (index + 1)));

    })
    el.style.minHeight = ""
  }

  self.update = function() {
    // loop from your example, with my logic added
    self.items..slice(lastKnownIndex + 1).forEach(function(item,index) {
          item.classList.add('op0')
    })
  
    if (self.items[0]) {
      el.classList.add("tinyMasonryLoaded")
      if (columns[0]) {
        el.style.minHeight = el.clientHeight + "px"
      }
      var tested = self.items[0]
      tested.style.width = ""
      if (tested.parentNode && tested.parentNode.parentNode === el) {
        layout(tested)
      } else {
        el.appendChild(tested)
        setTimeout(layout.bind(0, tested))
      }
    }
    
    // update index
    lastKnownIndex = self.items.length - 1
  }

  self.items = [].slice.call(el.children)
  self.update()

  var resizer;
  var startWidth = window.innerWidth;

  function resizeTimeout() {
      clearTimeout(resizer);
      resizer = setTimeout(doneResizing, 100)
  } 

  function doneResizing() {
    var curWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var breakpoint = false;
      if ((startWidth >= 580 && curWidth < 580) || (startWidth <= 580 && curWidth > 580)) {
          breakpoint = true
      }
      else if ((startWidth >= 980 && curWidth < 980) || (startWidth <= 980 && curWidth > 980)) {
          breakpoint = true
      }
      if(breakpoint === true) {
          self.items.forEach(function(item,index) {
            item.classList.add('op0')
          })
          self.update()
      }
      startWidth = window.innerWidth;
  }

  window.addEventListener("resize", resizeTimeout)
}

if (typeof exports === "object") {
  module.exports = TinyMasonry
}

var masGridContainer = document.querySelector(".mas-grid");
var masGrid = new TinyMasonry(masGridContainer);
```

The important parts:

```
var lastKnownIndex = 0
```

introduces the variable to remember the index right at the top.

With your example loop in your update method:

```
// loop from your example, with my logic added
self.items..slice(lastKnownIndex + 1).forEach(function(item,index) {
      item.classList.add('op0')
})
```

see my example above.

```
// update index
lastKnownIndex = self.items.length - 1
```

at the end of your update method.

Comment: works great Thanks. I have tried to implement something very similar but did not slice the array thats why it applied style to all over and over.

Answer (score 0):

1. One way to tackle this issue is instead of just adding the item index, add an object. this object would have the item and the Date Object. So by comparing the date objects you'll be able to get the latest entries.
2. Option 2 is basically create a temp list and adding the entries into a new list and then form an union of them to get the common entries so that you know the new entries.

> ```
> eg:
>
> temp List 1 = [1,2]
>
> List 1 = [1,2,3]
> ```

So now you know 3 was the new entry.

Comment: Could you provide a functional example implemented in my code?